# Finding The Speed Of A Train Using Basic Trigonometry.

Tags: kinematics

Question: The wheel of a carriage is 3 feet in diameter and makes 3 revolutions per second; how fast is the train going?

I'm gonna walk myself through this and hopefully I get it right...

Well for starters, the radius of the wheel is 1.5 feet. 
So the circumference is $1.5\cdot2\cdot\pi=3\pi$ feet.
The wheel has three revolutions per second. So it is moving at $9\pi$ feet per second right?

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Assuming no slipping, yes.  This is hardly trigonometry though.

Comment: Why do you think its wrong